# При вводе в один Edittext это число появляется автоматически во 2 Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как реализовать ,у меня есть 8 Edittext ,мне нужно независимо в какой edittext я напишу число ,оно должно появиться сразу во всех других Edittext

Comment: Повесьте слушатель ввода текста и в нём остальным присваивайте. Вам нужен `TextWatcher`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Можно пример

Comment: [Android TextWatcher Example](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-textwatcher-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть решения - повесить на каждый `EditText` слушателя фокуса. Если элемент в фокусе - вешаем на него слушатель ввода текста `textWatcher`, который модифицирует все остальные `EditText`. Фокус ушел - снимаем `textWatcher`.

Вот решение для четырех элементов. Для восьми - аналогично.

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_2);
EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_3);
EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_4);

final EditText [] editTexts = new EditText[] {editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4};

final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {       }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {        }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
            if (!editText.hasFocus()) {
                editText.setText(s);
            }
        }
    }
};


for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
     editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            EditText chosenEditText = (EditText)view;
            if (b) {
                chosenEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }
            else {
                chosenEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: можете изменить код,чтоб например я ввел в первый edittext число, а во 2 edittext это число поделилось на 2